# Last Row Search

Tags: excel, vba

The following code is used to find the last row in Column C and then I need to add a formula into that column. At some time the column may be empty except for the header which I need to keep. Currently the formula overrides the header. Is there is simple way to keep the header. Any help would be appreciated

```
Dim lngLastrow As Long
lngLastrow = Range("C:C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: You question is not clear.

Comment: You can either do an `If Statement` to check if `lgnLastrow = 1` or simply add a `+ 1` to the end of your line to make the last row 1 extra row.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `If` statement to ensure the `lngLastrow` is not the header row would do the trick.

```
Dim lngLastrow As Long
lngLastrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lngLastrow > 1 Then
    'write formula
End If
```

Note that `"C:C" & Rows.Count` would result in something like `"C:C100"` which is not a valid address! It has to be `"C" & Rows.Count` instead.

Comment: Thank you for this. I had tried that but without success. However this time it has worked